# Add additional field in user model using django-custom-user

Tags: python, django

I am using this code https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user to login with email address. However, I wish to add contact number, first name and last name with the procedure it stated under Extending EmailUser model

I have added contact_number under class below in model.py

```
class MyCustomEmailUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    """
    Example of an EmailUser with a new field date_of_birth
    """
    contact_number = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=10)
```

I leave the class MyCustomEmailUserAdmin blank in admin.py

```
class MyCustomEmailUserAdmin(EmailUserAdmin):
    """
    You can customize the interface of your model here.
    """
    pass
```

When I log into the admin panel, under the Users, I only see email address, enter password and reenter password in the form to add user. I don't see contact number is there, any idea how should I proceed?

Comment: are these two admin classes or one? If you leave it blank what do you expect? You registered the (second) admin?

Comment: the top one is in model.py and the bottom one is in admin.py. I think I shouldnt leave it blank but how do I start in that blank class?